# Find Documents in MongoDB whose with an array field is a subset of a query array

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a insert a set of documents each with an `array` field. I would like to find all documents such that their `array` field is a subset of a query array. For example, if I have the following documents,

```
collection.insert([
  {
     'name': 'one',
     'array': ['a', 'b', 'c']
  },
  {
     'name': 'two',
     'array': ['b', 'c', 'd']
  },
  {
     'name': 'three',
     'array': ['b', 'c']
  }
])
```

and I query `collection.find({'array': {'$superset': ['a', 'b', 'c']})`, I would expect to see documents `one` and `three` as `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `['b', 'c']` are both subsets of `['a', 'b', 'c']`.  In other words, I'd like to do the inverse of Mongo's `$all` query, which selects all documents such that the query array is a subset of the document's `array` field.  Is this possible? and if so, how?

Comment: You'd need to do some aggregation IMHO.

Answer (score 11):

In MongoDb, for array field:

```
"$in:[...]" means "intersection" or "any element in",
"$all:[...]" means "subset" or "contain",
"$elemMatch:{...}" means "any element match"
"$not:{$elemMatch:{$nin:[...]}}" means "superset" or "in"
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a simple way to do this with aggregation framework or with a find query.

Find query is simple, but you have to use $elemMatch operator:

```
> db.collection.find({array:{$not:{$elemMatch:{$nin:['a','b','c']}}}}, {_id:0,name:1})
```

Note that this indicates that we want to not match an array which has an element which is (at the same time) not equal to 'a', 'b' or 'c'.  I added a projection which only returns the name field of the resultant document which is optional.

Answer (score 4):

To do this within the context of aggregation, you can use [`$setIsSubset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Project the original doc and a new field that indicates if array
    // is a subset of ['a', 'b', 'c']
    {$project: {
        doc: '$$ROOT',
        isSubset: {$setIsSubset: ['$array', ['a', 'b', 'c']]}
    }},
    // Filter on isSubset
    {$match: {isSubset: true}},
    // Project just the original docs
    {$project: {_id: 0, doc: 1}}
])
```

Note that `$setIsSubset` was added in MongoDB 2.6.

Comment: nice one.  I removed the old inefficient aggregation from my answer as this is much more elegant and it's now been available for a while.