# MongoDB match documents with all elements in a given array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an array

```
solvedProblemIds = [0,2]
```

and I want to query for documents that have ALL of the elements in their requiredProblems array inside the solvedProblemIds array.

for example, if these are my documents:

```
{
    id: 0,
    name: "Problem 1",
    points: 10,
    description: "Problem 1 desc",
    requiredProblems: []
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Problem 2",
    points: 10,
    description: "Problem 2 desc",
    requiredProblems: [0]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Problem 3",
    points: 10,
    description: "Problem 3 desc",
    requiredProblems: [0]
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Problem 4",
    points: 10,
    description: "Problem 4 desc",
    requiredProblems: [0, 2]
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "Problem 5",
    points: 10,
    description: "Problem 5 desc",
    requiredProblems: [0, 1, 2, 3]
}
```

The query should match the documents with id 3, 2, 1, and 0.
I looked at the $in selector, but it only requires ONE element to be in the array, not all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Documents in MongoDB whose with an array field is a subset of a query array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109351/find-documents-in-mongodb-whose-with-an-array-field-is-a-subset-of-a-query-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no operator that works out of the box for determining a subset. You can either do an aggregation (I haven't thought about how) or the following:

```
{ $not: { $elemMatch: { $nin: [0, 2] } } }
```

This is finding documents such that there exists no elements that are not in [0, 2].