# MongoDB - Looking up documents based on criteria defined by the documents themselves

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-design, database-schema

Overall, I am trying to find a system design to quickly look up stored objects whose metadata matches data bundled on incoming events. Which fields are required, however, are themselves part of the stored objects, and are not fields that I can hardcode into a lookup query.

My system has a `policies` collection stored in MongoDB with documents that look like this:

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: "Jason's Policy",
    requirements: {
        "var1": "aaa",
        "var2": "bbb"
        // could have any number more, and each policy can have different field/values under requirements
    }
}
```

My system receives events that look like this:

```
// Event 1 - matches all requirements under above policy
{
    id: 777,
    "var1": "aaa",
    "var2": "bbb"
}

// Event 2 - does not match all requirements from above policy since var1 is undefined
{
    id: 888,
    "var2": "bbb",
    "var3": "zzz"
}
```

As I receive events, how can I efficiently look up all the policies whose requirements are fully satisfied by the values received in the event?

As an example, in the sample data above, event 1 should return the policy (since var1 and var2 match the policy requirements), but event 2 should *not* return the policy (since var1 does not match/ is missing).

I can think of brute-force ways to do this on the application server itself (think nested `for` loops) but efficiency will be key as we receive hundreds of events per second.

I am open to recommendations for document schema changes that can satisfy the general problem (looking up documents based on criteria itself defined in our documents). I am also open to any overall design recommendations that address the problem, too (perhaps there is a better way to structure our system to trigger policy actions in response to events).

Thanks!

Comment: So for an event to match a policy all its keys (except for `id`) AND values have to match those of the policy, correct?

Comment: Hi, having a `events` document, you want to get all the `policies` documents, that matches all requirements policy. Am i right?

Comment: Yes! All policy keys and values must be matched. The events may have extra data (which I can ignore), but I need to return a list of policies where the event data matches ALL of the 'poicy.requirements' fields.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the exact scenario but can think of 2 here,

1. You need an exact match. For that you can run the below `querydb.getCollection('test').find({'requirements':{'var1':'aaa','var2':'bbb'}})`
   for above query to run you need to save requirements object after sorting it's keys var1 and var2.
2. You need to match all properties exists and don't care if anything is extra in policies collection. You need to change policies being stored as,

> 

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("603250b0775428e32b9b303f"),
        "id" : 123,
        "name" : "Jason's Policy",
        "requirements" : {
            "var1" : "aaa",
            "var2" : "bbb"
        },
        "requirements_search" : [ 
            "var1aaa", 
            "var2bbb", 
            "var3ccc"
        ]
    }
```

then you can run the below query,

```
db.getCollection('test').find({'requirements_search':{'$all' : ['var1aaa','var2bbb']}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Your second answer is close to what I am looking for. The one difference is that I need to match all properties that exist in the policy itself, and I don't care about any extra properties in the event.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question in another post: [Find Documents in MongoDB whose with an array field is a subset of a query array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109351/find-documents-in-mongodb-whose-with-an-array-field-is-a-subset-of-a-query-array).

MongoDB offers a `$setIsSubset` operator that can check if a document's array values are a subset of the array values in a query. Translated to my use case: if a given policy's requirements are a subset of the event's metadata, then I know that the event data fully meets the requirements for that policy.

For completeness, below is the MongoDB aggregation that solved my problem. I still need to research if there is a more efficient overall system design to facilitate what I need, but at a minimum, this Mongo aggregation will fetch the results that I need.

```
// Requires us to flatten policy requirements into an array like the following
//
// {    
//     "id" : 123,
//     "name" : "Jason's Policy",
//     "requirements" : [ 
//         "var1_aaa", 
//         "var2_bbb" 
//     ]
// }
//
// Event  matches all policy requirements and has extra unrelated attributes
// {
//     id: 777,
//     "var1": "aaa",
//     "var2": "bbb",
//     "var3": "ccc"
// }

db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        doc: '$$ROOT',
        isSubset: {$setIsSubset: ['$requirements', ['var1_aaa', 'var2_bbb', 'var3_ccc']]}
    }},
    {$match: {isSubset: true}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, 'doc.name': 1}}
])
```